# When partitioning devices for zfsonlinux, what is the correct "Partition type GUID" to use, or is this important at all?

Tags: partitioning, gpt, zfs

I want to use zfsonlinux on a Debian system.
Since I have advanced format drives and will employ LUKS, I have to partition the device by hand. [A forum entry at archlinux.org](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1255611) points out that the property "Partition type GUID", which has to be specified for every partition is not used in Linux anyway. gdisk by default naturally suggests

8300 (Linux filesystem).

I have found [at least one tutorial](http://www.funtoo.org/ZFS_Install_Guide) which instead uses

bf00 (Solaris root).

Based on my search around the web, it doesn't matter at all as long as you don't expose the drives to other OSes, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I stuck with the default setting (8300) and everything is running fine.
Cheers!